# ¿Como recargar resultado AJAX sin perder su valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Cuando muestro un resultado con AJAX ¿Como puedo hacer para que con un botón al hacer click actualice ese resultado (no la página)? ya que si lo hago con un reload con JAVASCRIPT me recarga la pagina y se pierde el resultado que obtuve de AJAX

Comment: Ivxn coloca algo de código, para buscar una solución...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me imagino que debes de tener un evento **onclick** y envias un dato en específico a una función algo así:

```
<input type="button" onclick="nombreFuncion(dato); return false;" >
```

para evitar que recargue toda la página, carga el resultado que te arroja el [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) en un div, algo asi:

```
<div id="divCarga"></div>
```

este sería el ajax, me imagino que debes de tener algo similar:

```
function nombreFuncion(data){
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url',
      dataType:"html",
      data: data,
      beforeSend:function(){

     },
     success:function(response){
        $('#divCarga').html('cargara lo siguiente'+response);
      }
    });
```

}

**NOTA**

recuerda que el **input** no debe de ser tipo submit, asi evitaras que recargue toda la página

Comment: Tenga o no el button de `type="submit` puede entrar" solo habrá que agregar una linea mas a la función para evitar el doble envio `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Siempre he tenido ese problema y mejor proceder por no utilizar  el submit, gracias por  el aporte :)

Answer (score 1):

Dale ejecutar y pruebalo. Saludos

```js
$(document).on('click', '.borrar', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
<tr id="fila0">
  <td>Columna 1.1</td>
  <td>Columna 1.2</td>
  <td>Columna 1.3</td>
  <td>Columna 1.4</td>
  <td>Columna 1.5</td>
  <td>Columna 1.6</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fila1">
  <td>Columna 2.1</td>
  <td>Columna 2.2</td>
  <td>Columna 2.3</td>
  <td>Columna 2.4</td>
  <td>Columna 2.5</td>
  <td>Columna 2.6</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fila2">
  <td>Columna 3.1</td>
  <td>Columna 3.2</td>
  <td>Columna 3.3</td>
  <td>Columna 3.4</td>
  <td>Columna 3.5</td>
  <td>Columna 3.6</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fila3">
  <td>Columna 4.1</td>
  <td>Columna 4.2</td>
  <td>Columna 4.3</td>
  <td>Columna 4.4</td>
  <td>Columna 4.5</td>
  <td>Columna 4.6</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fila4">
  <td>Columna 5.1</td>
  <td>Columna 5.2</td>
  <td>Columna 5.3</td>
  <td>Columna 5.4</td>
  <td>Columna 5.5</td>
  <td>Columna 5.6</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando algun tipo de input, podrias agregar una funcion en js

```
function refresh() {
        var dato1 = String(document.getElementById("dondeobtienevalor").value);
        document.getElementById("dondesemostrara").value = (dato1);
    }
```

sin olvidar agregar (onkeyup o onclick)
="refresh();" a tu elemento